# Check checkboxes selected

Tags: php, checkbox

I know I can see if a checkbox is selected with something like

```
if (isset($_POST['option1']))
```

But if I have like 5 checkboxes, how can I immediately see which ones are selected? I have do to an if statement to all of them?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? What are you trying to do? some code should be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check them within an iteration.

```
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
   if (isset($_POST['option'.$i]))
   {
        //do stuff...
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

For a checkbox with the same name use square brackets i.e.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1" /> Option 1
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2" /> Option 2
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="3" /> Option 3
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="4" /> Option 4
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="5" /> Option 5
```

Then `$_POST['option']` will be an array of values ticked.

Answer (score -1):

If you have something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="option1">option1
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="option2">option2
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="option3">option3
```

in php, `$_POST["options"]` will be an array of the selected options

```
foreach($_POST['options'] as $opt) {
  echo "selected option: $opt <br />";
}
```

you could also use `array_flip()`, so the array keys are the option values...

Comment: my bad, forgot something essential, adding []

Comment: guess you are confused with radio buttons

Comment: Correct. Your answer is now identical to @fire's.

Answer (score -2):

For a given form:

```
<select name="foo">
   <option value="opt1" selected="selected">bar</option>
   <option value="opt2">whatever</option>
 </select>
```

`<?php echo $_POST['foo'] ?>` will print out "opt1".